# Why does mysqldump require drop command?

Tags: mysql, mysqldump

I am trying to backup a large table and after reading various other answers on this site have tried

```
mysqldump --user=user --password=password dbname1 tablename | mysql --user=user --password=password dbname2
```

I get the error

```
DROP command was denied to user 'user'@'localhost' for table tablename
```

which scares me. This is the first time I've worked with such a large DB and thus needed to use mysqldump, so I don't know what's going on. Why would it need the DROP command? I want to basically copy the table into another database, not modify (or delete) the existing one in any way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default `mysqldump` will output commands to drop tables, if they exist. This is why you get the error. It doesn't come from the `mysqldump` command, but from the `mysql` command you are piping the commands to. The user doesn't have permission to drop the table.

You can append `--skip-add-drop-table` to the `mysqldump` command to remove the `DROP TABLE` commands, but then you will get errors if the tables exist.

[mysqldump parameters](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqldump.html)